# Getting a segfault where gdb doesn't recognize

Tags: c

I am trying to print out the contents of a 2 dimensional array starting from a certain location in the array (since not all elements of the array are filled). The array contains pointers to a data structure I created called a node. Here is the print code:

```
    void repository_print(int print_elements){
        node *travTemp;
        travTemp = main_list[highest_level][0];
        while((travTemp->down)!=NULL){
          while((travTemp->next)!=NULL){
              printf(" {%d, %d}", travTemp->key, travTemp->d);
              travTemp = travTemp->next;
           }
           travTemp = travTemp->down;
           printf("\n");
        }
    }
```

Basically the array holds pointers to node elements in a sorted fashion. Each node contains a "key" attribute and a "d" attribute and I am just trying to go level by level and print out the {key, d} records cleanly. I keep getting a segfault when I call the print command in my main. I tried using gdb to debug it but it won't give me an actual line. It just says:

```
   #0 0x0000000000400b2e in repository_print ()
   #1 0x0000000000400722 in main ()
```

Does anyone how I can find the seg fault or why the seg fault is occurring? Thanks.

EDIT:

I did try compiling with -g and found that the error is occurring at the line "while((travTemp->next)!=NULL)". This is confusing to me because this attribute should not be NULL. I'll have to check the rest of my code. The main_list declaration is as follows in case anyone needs to know:

```
    node *main_list[MAX_HEIGHT][MAX_LEVEL];
```

EDIT:

So following Felipe's advice I changed my print function to the following:

```
    node *travTemp;
    travTemp = main_list[highest_level][0];

    while(travTemp!=NULL && (travTemp->down)!=NULL){
        printf(" {%d, %d}", travTemp->next->key, travTemp->next->d);
        travTemp = travTemp->next;
    }

    travTemp = main_list[highest_level+1][0];
    printf("\n");
```

However, now, I'm getting a seg fault at the print statement line. If travTemp->next does not equal NULL what's the problem with travTemp->next->key? I have no idea why since these values should exist in the repository.

Comment: Did you compile with `-g`? Also, show us the declaration of `main_list`. Is it a true 2D array?

Comment: How much of the array gets printed before the segfault?

Comment: Not one bit of the array, but I found out where the error occurs, I'm just not sure why :/

Comment: Are you sure the error is in the line you say it is? It's not on the *outer* loop?

Comment: Compile with `-g` *and* with `-O0` (that's 'minus letter-O zero'). Optimisation can be confusing.

Answer (score 1):

If main_list[highest_level][0] is NULL, then your initial attempt to test travTemp->next will fail.  @Filipe has addressed getting more debugging info in the comments.

*Update*: if it isn't NULL but following travTemp seems to be the problem, perhaps it is some other illegal value.  Not seeing how main_list was filled, can't say more than that.

Comment: I added a print statement to check if travTemp was NULL but it did not print, so I don't think it is NULL.

Comment: @JeremyFisher Did you `fflush(stdout)` after `printf`?